# Timeout from .NET but not from sql-server console

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a query which takes 10 seconds from the sql-server console but I get  timeout from a program written in VB (language).
What can be the reason that I get timeout from my program but works fine from sqlserver console?

My code:

```
Public Shared Function GetDataSet(ByVal vCommandType As CommandType, ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal sqlParams() As SqlParameter) As DataSet

    Dim oConn As New SqlConnection(bbdd.connectionString)
    Dim DC As New SqlCommand()
    DC.CommandTimeout = 600   --- with this, my query is works fine
    DC.CommandText = strSQL
    DC.CommandType = vCommandType
    DC.Connection = oConn

    If Not IsNothing(sqlParams) Then
        DC.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams)
    End If

    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(DC)
    Dim DS As New DataSet

    Try
        DA.Fill(DS)
        Return DS
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        oConn.Close()
        DA.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: how are you communicating with database, using entity framework?

Comment: What is the timeout in your connection setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite common and can have many causes.  SQL Server probably uses a different plan cache for SSMS and your application.  And if the execution plans are different, execution time can vary wildly.

SQL Server optimizes for particular values of parameters.  So if the first query you send uses parameters that give a good execution plan, you're in luck.  Next invocations of the same query will re-use that plan.  But it's also possible to choose parameters that give a bad execution plan.  This is called "parameter sniffing".

For a detailed explanation, see [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout in sqlcommand object like this:

```
// Setting command timeout to 60 second
     DC.CommandTimeout = 60;
```